# Fabric 3.4.0 Text formatting

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have been working on Fabric `3.4.0` and want to know how do I format the text, something show here [IText tests](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html)

I have been using `1.5.0` version and it works fine but it doesn't work on the latest version can someone help me fix the issue with the cdn on [`3.4.0`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js)

```js
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canv');

var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: '#333',
  lineHeight: 1.1,
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: 80 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
      4: { fontSize: 20 }
    }
  }
});

canvas.add(iTextSample);

function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onclick'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}

function setStyle(object, styleName, value) {
  if (object.setSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) {
    var style = { };
    style[styleName] = value;
    object.setSelectionStyles(style);
  }
  else {
    object[styleName] = value;
  }
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
  return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing)
    ? object.getSelectionStyles()[styleName]
    : object[styleName];
}


addHandler('underline', function(obj) {
  var isUnderline = (getStyle(obj, 'textDecoration') || '').indexOf('underline') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'textDecoration', isUnderline ? '' : 'underline');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="underline">Underline it!!</button>

<canvas id="canv" width="250" height="300" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: 400px; height: 400px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After v2, `textDecoration` property is removed, and separated to [underline](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#underline), [overline](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#overline), [linethrough](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#linethrough) to support multiple text decoration.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canv');
var value = false;
var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: '#333',
  lineHeight: 1.1,
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: { underline: true, fontSize: 80 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
      4: { fontSize: 20 }
    }
  }
});

canvas.add(iTextSample);

function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onclick'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}


function getStyle(object, styleName) {
  return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing)
    ? object.getSelectionStyles()
    : object[styleName];
}


addHandler('underline', function(obj) {
  var selectionStyle = obj.getSelectionStyles();
  value = !value;
  if(selectionStyle.length)
    obj.setSelectionStyles({underline: value});
  else
    obj.setSelectionStyles({underline: value}, 0, obj.text.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<button id="underline">Underline it!!</button>

<canvas id="canv" width="250" height="300" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: 400px; height: 400px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, Is there a way to select the entire `element(canvas.getActiveObject()` and apply the style ??

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, you need to set for all individual characters, by providing start and end to setSelectionStyles.

Comment: You mean loop it all and then apply ? is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Cool man exactly what I was looking for thanks for the help! I was also able to do it but with iterations and others. This would be a much better approach to solve the same